# grails 3 spring security - authentication does not working

Tags: grails, spring-security

I tried to update simple project from grails 2.4.2 to 3.2.0 and seems everything works except spring security.

The problem is that /login/auth page always redirects to /login/auth?login_error=1 even if corrected user from BootStrap.groovy trying to login:

BootStrap.groovy

```
def init = { servletContext ->

        def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)

        def testUser = new Person(username: 'me', password: 'password')
        testUser.save(flush: true)

        PersonRole.create testUser, adminRole, true


    }
```

application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'simple.Role.Person'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'simple.Role.PersonRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'simple.Role'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
   [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/login/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/logout/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
   [pattern: '/simple/**',      access: ['ROLE_ADMIN']]   
]
```

Please point the right direction - where can be the issue?

Comment: have you set grails.serverURL in your application.groovy ?

Comment: grails.serverURL = "http://<ip>:<port>/<application name>"  configure grails.serverURL in this format into application.groovy

Comment: setting grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/simple" does not cause redirect to /login/auth?login_error=1, but still not able to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in custom login and logout gsp. New version has no compatibility, need to re-create it.
Deleting login.gsp/logout.gsp solved the issue.